# Sending song information through spotify

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, spotify, libspotify

I've been scouring the internet for some sort of support for this and I cant seem to find much so I have to start a question.

I have a project where I am to display the track title, artists name, and other basic song information, on a separate physical display, much like those LED signs you'll see at stores.  In order for me to do this, I have to open some sort of pipeline from the spotify app (the app i'm going to create) to a serial port on the clients computer that eventually makes its way to the display.

Spotify apps run on basic web design languages (Javascript, HTML, CSS) so I figure I could use something like socket.io, although that seems to be more for a browser rather than a general javascript using application.  **So is there a way for me to open a pipeline from a server to a client using basic javascript that would be able to interact with spotify and a client?**

I apologize for the abstractness of this question, but I feel like I've explained it well enough

Comment: You've tagged this with "libspotify", but you're talking about writing Spotify Apps. These are two different APIs for two different purposes.  Libspotify is a native API for writing applications that run independently of the Spotify client. The Spotify Apps API is an HTML/Javascript-based API for writing apps that run in the Spotify API. You should probably either remove the libspotify tag or clarify what kind of app you're writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apps API supports WebSockets just fine, so you can write a server application that you run on `localhost` and have your Spotify App connect to it. Or, you could skip sockets and write a little REST API to run on `localhost` that your Spotify App calls with the relevant details every time a song changes.

However, be aware that Spotify Apps don't run forever. If your app isn't visible on-screen (say, if you've navigated elsewhere in Spotify), it'll get suspended after a few minutes.

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks!  I wasn't aware they ended.  I thought they had some kind of persistence like android apps.  That actually might cause a problem.